# Angular 11 CLI, "ng generate" option: --skip-tests

Tags: angular-cli

When using the Angular 11 CLI, when I [generate](https://angular.io/cli/generate) a new component I can specify the option `--skip-tests` to avoid generating a `.component.spec.ts` at this stage.

```
ng generate component --name asdf --module app --skip-tests --dry-run
```

When I generate a new module containing a new component (`--route` option) I can't specify the `--skip-tests` option.

```
ng generate module --name asdf --module app --route asdf --routing true --skip-tests --dry-run
```

If I do I get the error:

```
Unknown option: '--skip-tests'
```

Is there another way to skip generating the test in this case or is it just not supported for `generate module`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to [this article](https://tutorialsforangular.com/2019/12/31/skipping-tests-in-angular-cli/), you can either add the `--skip-tests` flag upon generating the project as a whole, or generating individual components. From a logical perspective, it makes sense that you could not apply the flag on a module, since modules are not generated with test files.

To make the change for all future generated code, modify your `angular.json` file by adding the `skipTests:true` to the schematics section.

```
 "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, the article you linked actually indirectly contains the answer which would be to manually edit the "schematics" in `angular.json` adding `"skipTests": true` under `"@schematics/angular:component"`. I tried it out, it works, and that would be the best option for me. If you want to add that to your answer I believe I can mark it as correct.

Comment: You should also add one for `@schematics/angular:guard"`.

Answer (score 7):

`--skip-tests` is not supported by the `ng generate module` command.

[supported options are :](https://angular.io/cli/generate#module)

- `--flat`
- `--lint-fix`
- `--module`
- `--project`
- `--route`
- `--routing`
- `--routing-scope`

**UPDATE:**

an alternative is to use two commands sequencially:

```
ng generate module --name am && ng generate component --name ac --module am --skip-tests --dry-run
```

`&&` means Execute command2 only if the execution of command1 has finished successfully.

**note that && is not supported in vscode integrated terminal**, possible workaround can be find [here](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/491)

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Am using angular CLI version 10, but angular cli v11 should yield the same results.

Answer (score 4):

Skip the test file with this command: **ng g c name --skip-tests**

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Angular CLI release notes. From what I understand, with Version 13.2.0-next.2 (2022-01-12), there has been an update, changing from --skipTest to --skip-tests. This means that if you are using a version of Angular CLI earlier than 13.2.0, you should use --skipTest. Otherwise, you need to use the --skip-tests expression.

For more information you can check the link below

> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases