# In Angular, how do I (if it's possible) create JUST a component's template (.component.html file) using Angular CLI from the terminal/command line?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-components, angular-template

Using the Angular CLI (v12), I want to create JUST the template view file (<component-name.component.html>) for an Angular (v12) component. I know that the command `ng generate component component-name` generates this file along with the .ts, .css, and .spec.ts files, but I only want to create a new template/view file associated with a particular component class, not the whole component. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

use `ng g c component-name --skip-tests --inline-style` for more info [Refer here](https://angular.io/cli/generate)

Answer (score 1):

[Angular 11 CLI, "ng generate" option: --skip-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242718/angular-11-cli-ng-generate-option-skip-tests/66242826)
This might help. In short, the answer is no, you can skip some stuff, but can't skip creating a .ts file, which is what a component is.